# Calculating standard deviation for defined values in a dataset error in R

Tags: r, standard-deviation

I want to calculate the standard deviation for x = [1:15], [1:1000]. I am looking for a way to get the standard deviation for every group of 15 - so 1000 standard deviations in total, but i cant find a formula for it.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. That includes a sample of data and a clear explanation of what you've tried and what hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `apply` over the margin `2`, e.g.,

```
apply(x,2,sd)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `matrix`, another option is `colSds` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
colSds(x)
```

---

Or another option is `dapply` from `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
dapply(x, fsd)
```